# Are Starships Randomly Generated or Standardized?

Tags: no-mans-sky

With the new pathfinder update, ships have been split into four classes: Shuttle, Fighter, Hauler or Explorer.

**Do these classes have a standardized set of starships within them or are they randomly generated in each star system? If they are randomized, is the randomization purely cosmetic?**

**Source:** https://www.nomanssky.com/pathfinder-update/

Answer (score 3):

From my experiences, yes, they do have a randomized set of characteristics, based around a central theme.

**Hauler**
Is generally boxy, and will have a raised cockpit. With some symmetrical wings, or thrusters. I usually find these in Vy'keen systems.

**Explorer**
Is usually based around a central sphere like cockpit and will have odd looking bits attached and will not be symmetrical. Usually a Korvax ship.

**Shuttle**
Long and flat, usually with two cylinders on each side. Find these most in Gex systems.

**Fighter**
Usually a 'pointy' ship, so will be flat, with a pointed cockpit and symmetrical wings.

**Exotic**
I think these are randomised, as my ship is just a small sphere with two large vertical fins, and is not classed as any of the above.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Not randomized. There is a full guide on starships here:
http://segmentnext.com/2016/08/09/no-mans-sky-starships-guide-types-upgrades-blueprints-destruction/

Comment: That article is from 2016. The question asks about what changed with the most recent update.

Comment: well it been updated hasnt it? No need to so easily vote down my answers, what is wrong with people here?

Comment: Considering the article only lists 3 ship types being explorer, fighter and traders, while in game there are 4 as in the question; I would say no, it was not updated.